# Is it possible to create an if statement in this sort of way?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an application that gives points to a certain item if the user answers in a certain way:

```
if (question1 == "Red" || "Green"){
        Apple++;
}
```

Will this setup give the variable apple- which is set to 0- 1 point? I have tried this and it will not work for some reason.

Comment: Both sides of the `||` need to involve the comparison to the `question1` variable.

Comment: It would be convenient if you could, but no, you have to specify the variable to compare each time. `if (question1 == "Red" || question1 == "Green")` is how you have to do it. What you've written now will be interpreted as `if (question1 == ("Red" || "Green"))`

Comment: No, that's not not how either of those operators works, but you could use `["Red", "Green"].includes(question1)`

Comment: Okay,  thank you guys! Can you post this separately so I can mark it as a solution?